# IDs and SubIDs for collision in AS3 SHMUP

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

My collision process involves checking simple hitbox and pixel perfect bitmap overlap before using object variables to determine if things SHOULD hit. Weapons, enemies, and objects have an ID number and collisionID array that say what should be able to affect what eg. ID = 1, collisionID = [2,3,4], ID 1 collision with ID 2, 3, or 4 are valid.

I want enemy bullets (which share an ID number with all other Weapon objects) to only be affected by a shield weapon. I figured I could make a subID variable, but I can't figure a concise way for that to be referenced. Below is the function that uses the current IDs.

```
    private function compareHitID(object1:WorldObject, object2:WorldObject):Boolean{
         var included:Boolean = false;
         if(object1 != null && object2 != null){
             for(var i:int = 0; i <= object1.collisionID.length - 1; i++){
                 if(object1.collisionID[i] == object2.gameID)
                         included = true;
                 }
         }
         return included;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to include subIDs, and store and reference them neatly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can enhance your ID set instead of making subIDs. After all you already have groups (weapons, enemies, bullets, etc) and you already have filters in place (collisionIDs). You then make "enemy bullet", "player bullet", "player shield", "enemy shield", "enemy", "player", etc (up to your fantasy) categories, and give em correct filters. For enemy bullets it'll be "player, player shield". This way enemy bullets will be affected by (collide with) player and player's shield, and pass through all other stuff. Also  you should first check if IDs are collideable, and only then do collision check.

Comment: This is waaaaay late, but thanks for the advice. I wish I would have checked back on this when you posted it, I only noticed the collision order a month ago. Thanks!